Intercept browser request with Selenium
I was wondering is it possible for Selenium to intercept a clicked link and instead open it in the Selenium instance of Chrome? As in, if I click a link in Discord can I have the link open in the Selenium instance instead of a standard Chrome instance?

You can not intercept a request started by browser with selenium. I think you can try these ways: 1) Simulate the headers and other conditions of that request and start a new request. 2) Intercept the request by using ansiable or mitmproxy and handle it with your python code.
